# How to get the logical structure of an academic article having pdf format(say IEEE) without using libraries like ParsCit

Tags: c#, pdf

Scientific article PDFs have a common structure say Paper title, Abstract, Introduction, Proposed scheme, Experiments, Conclusion, References and so on.
There will be sections and subsections for each structure element.

How can I accept a PDF document as input and get its physical structure in a formatted way(say XML format)
I want to get the physical structure of the PDF along with the data.

**I dont want to use any publicly available libraries like parsCit etc**

I am coding in C#.

Comment: *I dont want to use any publicly available libraries like parsCit etc* - So you want to code everything on your own? or would you at least accept a library for basic PDF access?

Comment: We have to minimize the use of external libraries as much as possible. Is there a method by which I can extract all text from a pdf and get the logical structure like sections and subsections? There are many methods to extract text from PDF. But how can I know the structure. Academic articles have similar structure. Anyone please help :-(

Comment: *Is there a method by which I can extract all text from a pdf* - as long as the PDF contains the required information: yes, implemented in various PDF libraries. *and get the logical structure like sections and subsections* - you'll have to develop heuristics for that if you don't want to use existing libraries. PDF files usually don't have semantic information like that, you have to deduce it from their layout.

Comment: Can you please explain some heuristics/ a strategy for that?

Comment: *Can you please explain some heuristics/ a strategy for that?* - I've not had to do something like that. Thus, no, I don't have such heuristics or strategies worked out.